# Double loop with random sampling

Tags: r

I wanted to generate score `i (0:36)` with frequency `j`. I wanted `j` loop to be random numbers. What I did was:

```
j<-1:70
for(i in 0:36) {
  for (j in 1:sample(j)) {
    print(i,j)
  }
}
```

But I got error. Should have I put `sample(j,1, replacement=TRUE)` instead of just `sample(j)`?
thank you

Comment: What error message did you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
for(i in 0:36) {
  for(k in 1:sample(70, 1)) {
    print(c(i,k))
  }
}
```

Comment: But, `print(i, k)` means "print i with k significant digits."  Did you mean `print(c(i,k))` ?

Comment: yes your code works. My error was warning message saying 1: In 1:sample(j) :
  numerical expression has 23 elements: only the first used
2: In 1:sample(j) :
  numerical expression has 17 elements: only the first used

Comment: I think I did not realize I need to use k to use the second loop. thank you so much for me to learn this.

Comment: I still get warnings with this solution since sample(j) returns a vector and 1:n doesn't like that...

Comment: @Tommy - Yes I was sloppy; -1 for me again.  `1:sample(1:70)` should at least become `1:sample(70, 1)`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want each element in `i` replicated from one to 70 times (randomly choosing the number of times to replicate the value).

```
i <- 0:36
j <- 1:70

#number of times to replicate each i
times <- sample(j, length(i), replace=FALSE)
result <- rep(i, times)
```

Whether to use replace=FALSE or not depends on how you'd like the sampling done (e.g. replace=FALSE assures that each j is chosen at most one time.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a random number, you should use `runif`. It has min/max to control the range. You can also use `sample`, but then it's better to use `sample.int(max, 1)`

```
j<-70
for(i in 0:36) {
  for (k in 1:runif(1,1,j)) {
    cat(i,k, "\n")
  }
}
```

Then the inner loop shouldn't overwrite `j` (which should be a constant) - so I renamed the loop variable to `k`.
...and `print` doesn't print multiple args like that - but `cat` does!